# Has Superman ever been this violent?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

Having just watched "Man of Steel", I have to wonder about the darker side of the movie. I've never heard of an instance before where

> he'd snapped peoples necks. Even for truly bad guys.

Is there any other reference of this in canon?

Answer (score 5):

There are times when Superman doesn't seem to care about killing. These tend to be non-humans such as Parademons, and advanced A.I. robots (like Brainiac). These days Superman tends to banish people to the Phantom Zone when they prove to be too much trouble.

Batman has accused Superman of overusing the Phantom Zone, basically as a way to kill people without going through the physical act, since they will never leave the Phantom Zone.

Answer (score 4):

In *Superman II* (the 1980 film with Christopher Reeve), Superman

> takes away Zod's powers by exposing him to Kryptonian sunlight (while Superman himself is protected by a crystal barrier) and then drops Zod into a deep pit

Superman isn't getting his hands dirty, so to speak, but his foe almost certainly would not have survived this event.

So Superman using violence is not exactly new. I think the events in *Man of Steel* got more attention because (1) they are more hands-on and visceral, and (2) the whole tone of the film is intentionally "darker" and more serious.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is along the lines of what you're asking but in Superman vs Darkseid Apokolips Now he literally beat Darkseid blind.